# Using libcurl in C++ application to send POST data from value in .INI file

Tags: c++, post, libcurl, ini

So I have a C++ application that takes a value from a key in a settings.INI file, uses libcurl to reach out to a PHP page, post that data, and it should return some different data.

And it actually works, aside from grabbing the data from the INI file. If I explicitely type in for the POSTFIELDS option for libcurl (e.i.: "Serial=454534" , instead of the variable storing the data that it retrived from my file).

Here's some code..
PHP:

```
<?
include("DBHeader.inc.php");
$Serial= $_POST['Serial'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `LockCodes` WHERE `sLockCode`=\"$Serial\"";
$RS=mysql_query($sql, $SQLConn);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($RS);

if ($num_rows>0)
{
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($RS))
  {
       echo $row['iLockCodeID'];
  }
}
else
{
  echo "...";
}


?>
```

Snippet of C++ code:

```
TCHAR szKeyValue[36];
GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Test"), _T("LockCode"), _T(""), szKeyValue, 36, _T("C:\\Test\\Settings.INI"));

CString sLockCode = szKeyValue;
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
CString Serial = _T("Serial=") + sLockCode;
string LCID;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://regserver2.nyksys.com/GetLCID.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Serial);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (data == _T("..."))
    {
        data = "0";
        AfxMessageBox("Invalid Serial Number");
        exit(0);
    }
```

My Settings.INI is in the standard format..

```
[Test]
LockCode=1D4553C7E7228E462DBAAE267977B7CDED8A
```

What happens is whenever I use the variable "Serial" instead of typing it in, the PHP page returns "..." instead of the desired result.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be TREMENDOUSLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have `_UNICODE` defined, which means that `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, `CString` is `CStringT<wchar_t>`, and the code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Serial);
```

actually passes a wide char string to `curl_easy_setopt()` when the function is expecting a narrow char string. If your machine is little Endian, then `curl_easy_setopt()` interprets the parameter as the string `"S\x00e\x00r\x00i\x00...` (on a Big Endian machine, it's `"\x00S\x00e\x00r\x00i...`) and because `curl_easy_setopt()` will use `strlen()` when `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` is not set, the entire POST request body on a little Endian machine is `S`. See, for example, http://codepad.org/JE2MYZfU

What you need to do is use narrow char strings:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(arr_id) ((sizeof (arr_id))/(sizeof ((arr_id)[0])))

char szKeyValue[36];
GetPrivateProfileStringA("Test", "LockCode", "", szKeyValue, ARRAY_LEN(szKeyValue), "C:\\Test\\Settings.INI");

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
CStringT<char> Body = CStringT<char>("Serial=") + szKeyValue;
string LCID;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://regserver2.nyksys.com/GetLCID.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Body);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
//...
```

Also, your PHP script looks vulnerable to SQL injection.

**EDIT:** One more thing. Are you setting `CURLOPT_POST` to 1?

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: Added the CURLOPT_POST and that did it.. hah! Thank you so much :)